# Set text to SaveAs dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, console-application

I have next task.
OS: Windows Server 2012 R2
We have run Windows Form application which try to Save file. But File name have length more than 255 chars and we get message.
[image]

I need to make console application that will cut file name and insert new filename in SaveAs dialog and press Save button.
[image]

I have issue with text inserting in File name field.
I used next code:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    public const uint WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;
    const int VK_F5 = 0x74;

    private static void InteropSetText(IntPtr iptrHWndDialog, string strTextToSet)
    {
        ///Step 1
        ///Find all parent controls on SaveAs dialog
        var list = GetChildWindows(iptrHWndDialog);

        ///Step 2
        /// Find control with className = "ComboBox"
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            string className = GetWindowClass(item);
            
            if (className != "ComboBox")
                continue;

            HandleRef hrefHWndTarget = new HandleRef(null, item);

            /// Step 3
            ///Set text in Control. 
            SendMessage(hrefHWndTarget, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, strTextToSet);

            /// Step 4
            //HACK: Without press F5 button New filename was not applied in Save dialog
            PostMessage(item, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F5, 0);
            return;
        }
    }
```

After Step 3 I can see new cut file name in control. But when I emulate Save press I get the same error message with long file name. It seems like new file name did not bind to control.

As hack I added Step 4 to emulate F5 button press. And it works on my work PC (Windows 10). But IT does not work on Windows Server 2012 R2

Any Idea ?

Comment: Are you trying to externally control a Windows Forms application from another process? If so, consider using [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview) to do it.

Comment: Server 2012 doesn't support paths over 260 characters. Upgrade the OS or install the program in a different place

Comment: @CaiusJard, my console application try to cut FileName.

Comment: @cai NTFS imposes a limit of 255 code units per path component. If your actual file name is longer than 255 characters, no amount of upgrading will make that issue go away.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/507293/windows-server-2012-file-name-too-long - two thigns confound you; filenames length 255 and overall path length 260

Comment: @cai The path length limit of 260 characters only matters, when you're using the ANSI API. The Unicode API has always supported path names with a length of up to 32k code units. All the way back to Windows NT 3.1. This question is about the **filename**, though, and that is limited by the file system, NTFS presumably, to 255 code units.

Comment: @IInspectable but `B302-20J Alison tutor group final sharing of slides from each team; discussion of what worked well & what might be developed for Block 5 collaboration; plus next steps on working together in Block 5 & individually towards the EMA_O.flv` is 235, whereas `c:\users\testuser0\documents\B302-20J Alison tutor group final sharing of slides from each team; discussion of what worked well & what might be developed for Block 5 collaboration; plus next steps on working together in Block 5 & individually towards the EMA_O.flv` is 265, so I think the limit being banged into is the 260 ..

Comment: (and also I thought, but less certain on this, that windows does change the error message appropriately when talking about too-long paths or too-long names; that error says "The *path* is too long")

Comment: #@Roman for clarity, I presume that you have some windows app that is saving this file, and it is asking the save location; you have no code or control over it, nor over the filename it suggests (like, you cannot alter the input name thereby influencing the output name), and you can't replace the app with something else more configurable, and it's being used in a server environment so there is no user to interact with it, so you're now trying to write *another* app that uses the first app and changes what it does - have you genuinely explored everything else? It's a bit XY problem - tell us X?

Comment: @CaiusJard, Hello. You are right. I have windows application, which try to save file. I have no code or control over it. To avoid problem with long file name I created console application. Console app used WinAPI to check file name, If file name more than 255 then Console application have to change filename for saving. 
My console application can detect SaveAs dialog, can detect combox with file name, can insert file name with lenth less 255 symbols. But new cut file name did not apply. And i get message about long file name too.

Comment: As Christian.K said, you should use UI automation not Windows hacking.